# Cannot get output to group correctly

Tags: vb.net

The code is supposed to output all of the items in the correct category at once. Instead, it is listing all of them individually.

It is supposed to look like this:

```
Living Room
Item Number-Item Description
Item Number-Item Description
Kitchen
Item Number-Item Description
Item Number-Item Description
Bathroom
Item Number-Item Description
Item Number-Item Description
```

Instead it is doing this:

```
Living Room
Item Number-Item Description
Kitchen
Item Number-Item Description
Bathroom
Item Number-Item Description
Living Room
Item Number-Item Description
Kitchen
Item Number-Item Description
Bathroom
Item Number-Item Description
```

---

```
Private Sub btnRoom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoom.Click

    Dim q = From asset In assets
          Let parts = asset.Split(","c)
          Let itemNumber = parts(0)
          Let itemDesc = parts(1)
          Let productCode = parts(2)
          Let purchaseDate = parts(3)
          Let purchasePrice = CDec(parts(4))
          Let currentValue = CDec(parts(5))
          Let life = parts(6)
          Let latestDate = parts(7)
          Let depreciation = depreciation(purchasePrice, currentValue)
          Let room = FindRoom(itemNumber.Substring(0, 3))
          Distinct


    lstDisplay.Items.Clear()
    lstDisplay.Items.Add("Assets Listed By Room")
    lstDisplay.Items.Add(" ")
    For Each thing In q

        lstDisplay.Items.Add("Item Number : " & thing.itemNumber &
                             " --- Item Description: " & thing.itemDesc)
    Next
End Sub

Function FindRoom(find As String) As String

    If find = "LVR" Then
        lstDisplay.Items.Add("Living Room")
    ElseIf find = "KIT" Then
        lstDisplay.Items.Add("Kitchen")
    ElseIf find = "REC" Then
        lstDisplay.Items.Add("Recreational Room")
    ElseIf find = "MBR" Then
        lstDisplay.Items.Add("Master Bedroom")
    ElseIf find = "SBR" Then
        lstDisplay.Items.Add("Second Bedroom")
    Else
        lstDisplay.Items.Add("Bathroom")
    End If
    Return find
End Function
```

Comment: `Handles` is not a VBA keyword. This is vb.net. I am changing the tag.

Comment: Sorry, my apologies.

Comment: If anyone should apologize, it should be Microsoft for creating this terminological confusion :)

Comment: Are you modifying someone else's code? I don't see any intent at grouping or sorting the data. Did you teacher cover any LINQ methods?

Comment: I have tried using `Group By itemNumber` but the program keeps crashing

Comment: This is all my code, the LINQ query is used multiple times throughout my program and I just modify that to perform what I need it to do.

Comment: can you post your `Group By` attempt?

Comment: `Let room = FindRoom(itemNumber.Substring(0, 3))`
              `Distinct`
           `Group By itemNumber`
           `Select itemDesc, itemNumber`

Comment: I am so terrible with this site. It won't format the code....

Comment: I'm not even completely sure if a `Group By` would fix it. This is our first program and we just learned LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample to get you started (not tested):

```
Private Sub btnRoom_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoom.Click

    Dim groups = assets.GroupBy(Function(line) line.Substring(0, 3))

    For Each group In groups

        Select Case group.Key
            Case "LVR" : lstDisplay.Items.Add("Living Room")
            Case "KIT" : lstDisplay.Items.Add("Kitchen")
            Case "REC" : lstDisplay.Items.Add("Recreational Room")
            Case "MBR" : lstDisplay.Items.Add("Master Bedroom")
            Case "SBR" : lstDisplay.Items.Add("Second Bedroom")
            Case "BAT" : lstDisplay.Items.Add("Bathroom")
            Case Else : lstDisplay.Items.Add(group.Key)
        End Select

        For Each line In group

            Dim parts = Split(line, ",", 3)

            lstDisplay.Items.Add("Item Number : " & parts(0) & 
                        " --- Item Description: " & parts(1))
        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you so much. What is the `group.Key` code? We haven't gone over that yet.

Comment: the [`.GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501) LINQ extension gets a list of [IGrouping<TKey, TElement>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977) groups where each group's `.Key` property has the value used to group by (`line.Substring(0, 3)`). I can't think of a simpler way to explain it, so it might be easier to step through the code with the debugger to see the groups.